# Retrofit error handling

Tags: java, android, error-handling, retrofit

I wrapped my Retrofit code in a class like below. If it's not clear from the code I'm posting it's interacting with a restful service with OAuth.

What would be a good way to do error handling? The REST server returns an error message in json format. I would like to act on that message by throwing some exceptions from my class. I'm trying to do something like below. But is this good design? Is mixing callbacks and exception throwing a good idea? Is there a better way?

With the approach below I could get i18l messages from within my custom exceptions and toast them to the user.

```
public class RestClient implements IRestClient {
    private IRestAPI api;

    /**
     *
     * @param accessToken
     */
    public RestClient(final String accessToken)
    {
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            }
        };

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.ENDPOINT)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
        api = restAdapter.create(IRestAPI.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestSomething(final Callback callback) {
        api.getSomething(new Callback<Something>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Something something, Response response) {
                callback.success(something, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if(error.getMessage().getId().euqals(ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED))
                {
                    throw new AccessTokenExpired();
                }
                else if(error.getMessage().getId().euqals(USER_NOT_FOUND))
                {
                    throw new UsernamePasswordNotFound();
                }
                else // something else happened...
                {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteSomething(final Callback callback) {
        api.deleteSomething(new Callback<Something>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Something something, Response response) {
                callback.success(something, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if(error.getMessage().getId().euqals(SOMETHING_NOT_FOUND))
                {
                    ...
                    ...
                    Different exceptions
                }
                ...
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Naturally I would have to create my own call back interface with only a success method.

Comment: You could always use Retrofit's ErrorHandler in the RestAdapter builder. http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/ErrorHandler.html

Answer (score 8):

When you build the `RestAdapter`, you can provide an [error handler](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/ErrorHandler.html) that maps out to your custom exceptions, it bypasses the call to `failure` in the `Callback<T>` on anything 4xx/5xx.  As a really contrived example:

```
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoints e = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://google.com")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
                        switch (cause.getResponse().getStatus()) {
                            case 400:
                                /* Handle the expected body format */
                                cause.getBody();
                                throw new RuntimeException("Bad Request");
                            default:
                                /* Things and stuff */
                                throw new RuntimeException("");
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build()
                .create(Endpoints.class);

        e.getGoogle(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
                System.out.println("Got it");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                System.err.println("This won't ever be seen due to the error handler.");
            }
        });
    }

    private static interface Endpoints {
        @GET("/foo/bar")
        void getGoogle(Callback<Response> callback);
    }
}
```

*edit*:  By doing this, however, you're potentially sacrificing a big reason why you'd want to use the `Callback` interface to begin with.  If this is a common use you will need, it may make more sense to use the sync calls and return your object type.  I don't fully know your use to say that's necessary, but it seems as though it may be more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, but I want different exceptions for different methods... or at least I think I do. I'm not too sure about this approach entirely. Say I have a createSomething method. That might throw a AlreadyExistsException. If I have a deleteSomething method it might throw SomethingNotFoundException... makes sense?

Comment: I really don't think you do, not at this level at least.  Any HTTP service that you are consuming should use standard error codes (or have some standard to tell you why the request failed).  So in the `switch` example in my answer and using your comment as a template, you would map out `409` to your `ConflictException`, `404` to your `NotFoundException` as the status code:exception mapping.  When you call something that gives a 4xx/5xx - regardless of what it is, you'll get a standard exception back.

Comment: Granted, the negative side of this is you're sacrificing some of the  nice nature of an async call by throwing back in other code, if you're expecting this to be a common thing - perhaps using the `Callback` interface is the wrong approach for your use.

Comment: Well the thing is I might get a 404 while not being able to find a user and an article. But I want different error messages. Also this isn't just about http error codes... Trying to delete a user or an article would also result in different codes for different cases

Comment: Seems like a delete on any resource would either be 2xx or 4xx (some type of success, or some type of failure). As far as messages - you get the body back to do with what you want. If the response json on error sounds to be some type of standard, you can deserialize it and use whatever pieces to build your exceptions very easily.

Comment: Sure, but the response might not be suitable for the user to see. Programmers then not to write too user friendly messages. Thus I want to make my own. Internationalized too... and it will be different weather it's an article, a user or a food item which I'm deleting. So I need custom responses for each method in my client.

Comment: What's missing for me is... where do I put the try/catch block?

Comment: @MikeWallaceDev That really depends on what you're doing.  If you are returning an `Observable<T>`, then that logic is done in the `onError` method of your `Subscriber`, if you are doing callbacks I am not sure (I've not really used those, I use Rx instead), if you are doing standard `Response` or Concrete Classes, then you'd wrap the HTTP call (if appropriate).  e.g. `try { myImplSyncronous.getResource(); } catch (RetrofitError e) { /*handle*/}`